# Adding space between elements

Tags: html, css

I have a .nav-bar element which is a child element with the property

```
display:flex; 
justify-content:space-evenly
```

When I set the header element which is the parent with the property the .nav-bar element child items tend to come together.

```
display:flex; 
justify-content:space-between;
```

However, removing the display property from the header seems to solve the issue partially.
Also when using the gap property in the .nav-bar element all seems well the children items are spaced. Why is this?

```
<!----CSS--FILE---->
    header {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav-bar {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      gap: 3rem;
    }

<!--javascript-file-->

    <header>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="40px" />
      
      <ul className="nav-bar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Yeah i am working with react but i have no problem with that my main question is why when i assign the ``display:flex; justify-content:space-between;`` on the header element I can't use ``display:flex; justify-content:space-between;`` on the nav-bar element. The current solution i am using is the ``gap`` property

Comment: I didn't ask for a recap of your problem. I'm _strongly hinting_ that the demo above doesn't work properly because of that syntax issue, and it's misleading, as you can see from the answer below. Please fix it. I would, but that's frowned upon here by some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace className by class in your HTML. You can still use space-evenly in your .nav-bar. (you can also set a width to your .nav-bar:100% to let them cover the whole free space)

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-bar {
  width:100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="40px" />
  
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: @mehdi i removed the gap property from the .nav-bar class and it seems the spaces between the list items ``li``  is removed. Is there any reason the ``justify-content:space-between`` can't work on its own

Comment: @isherwood, yes you are corect it was misleading and could have been a syntax error and not using React (as seen sometimes)

Comment: @alson justify-content in your.nav-bar should still work  even when removing the gap but only if you give it a width

Comment: You very welcome, glad we could help.